# v date picker not calling change event when single date is picked

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to detect the change event of date picker. It was working fine when user selects multiple days from the calendar. But if user selects a single date, change method not get triggered. My attempt is as below.

```
<v-date-picker
        v-model="dates"
        range
        color="primary"
        id="calendar1"
        @change="sendRange"
      ></v-date-picker>
sendRange(): void {
  console.log("executed") // executed for multiple date range selection only
}
```

Where I was get wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `@input` it will be invoked when a single date selected when the picker is in range mode

> Reactive date picker emits input even when any part of the date (year/month/day) changes, but change event is emitted only when the day (for date pickers) or month (for month pickers) changes. If range prop is set, date picker emits change when both [from, to] are selected.

check the documentation

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-date-picker/#events